# Z-Score To Percentile Conversion In Swift

Tags: swift, math, statistics

I am creating an app that requires using standard score. There is no problem in obtaining the z-value, but I want to convert it into a percentile. Does anyone know how to do such a thing in Swift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are talking about the Normal Distribution. The percentile is simply the Cumulative Distribution Function. Have a look at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) for the formula. That can be translated into code as:

```
func percentile (zscore z: Double) -> Int {
    let tmp = 0.5 * (1 + erf(z / sqrt(2.0)))
    return Int(round(tmp * 100))
}
```

You can check the result with a Z-score to percentile calculator, such as [this one](http://www.measuringu.com/pcalcz.php). Remember to select a single-tailed score.

Comment: how to display result in one sided ?